# Is it possible to snatch and host a win32 hwnd control in a child Winforms window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I did a search online but they are talking about how to do this for WPF.

Imagine a win32 application like shown below, and assume the app itself allows creating new Windows Forms windows as child windows. So they can talk to each other, I can send keypresses, and control the parent application.

What I want to do is to strip that listview outlined in the image and host it on my Winforms window. So it's hosted inside my Winforms window floating on top, and moves the control as my Winforms window moves.

I can get the hWnd handle from the parent app's .NET API but I am not sure if what I want is possible. If so, how?

[image]

Comment: You cannot expect this to work. You'll need to find a different solution.

Comment: Why do you say that? This can be done for WPF, right? Then why not Winforms?

Comment: I don't see this being viable for any framework. You cannot expect to lift a control from one process and host it as a child control in another process. Certainly not without the consent of the other app.

Comment: Thanks but the winforms app runs under the main app so they are the same process no?

Comment: Apps are usually in different processes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually there's nothing stopping you doing exactly that. You can take one process's window (or anything identifiable by an HWND) and set it as the child of another process's window. It will look like it belongs to the new parent, but it's message pump belongs to the original process.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the different-application angle, you can host a Win32 window inside of WinForms with the [NativeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score -4):

If you use the SetParent function, then it works just as you expect:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setparent

You might have to move the control to an appropriate location in your Winforms window and possibly resize it too, using the MoveWindow function:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.movewindow