# How can I process a win32 control's message in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I have a win32 control that's hosted inside a Winforms window. I want to process this control's messages so I can for example choose to ignore certain messages. The win32 control is a ListView control.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `System.Windows.Forms.Message`? Override `WndProc`. Edit: Nevermind the `Windows.Forms.Message` part. A Win32 control probably wont have that. My bad,

Comment: Thanks I am not sure how it works, but will the message windows is sending be limited to this win32 control or the winforms app? I just want to process the messages of the win32 control.

Comment: I think winforms has a ListView does it not? Either way, do you have the `hWnd` to the control?

Comment: Yes it does but I need to host this win32 listview because my app lives under this win32 legacy app. I have the hwnd and I used it to set its parent to my winforms app, so now it follows my winforms window.

Comment: Looks like a follow up to this hijack attempt: [is-it-possible-to-snatch-and-host-a-win32-hwnd-control-in-a-child-winforms-window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397374/)

Comment: @Henk, yes I already got it working though. Just need to "tame" it so it behaves more predictable.

Comment: It is beneficial for readers and would-be aswerers to know of related questions. And when you got that working, update your q/a ratio by posting a self-answer.

Comment: Ok will update that question.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the method WndProc in the Form class

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
         // use the 'm' struct
    }

}
```

---

A detailed example is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace csTempWindowsApplication1
{
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        // Constant value was found in the "windows.h" header file.
        private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
        private bool appActive = true;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main() 
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300,300);
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
        {
            // Paint a string in different styles depending on whether the 
            // application is active. 
            if (appActive) 
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.ActiveCaption,20,20,260,50);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Application is active", this.Font, SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, 20,20);
            }
            else 
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.InactiveCaption,20,20,260,50);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Application is Inactive", this.Font, SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, 20,20);
            }
        }

    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
        {
            // Listen for operating system messages. 
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                // The WM_ACTIVATEAPP message occurs when the application 
                // becomes the active application or becomes inactive. 
                case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:

                    // The WParam value identifies what is occurring.
                    appActive = (((int)m.WParam != 0));

                    // Invalidate to get new text painted. 
                    this.Invalidate();

                    break;                
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```